# Spark Sql Hive sql query with more than one limit clause

Tags: sql, hive, limit, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Hive and spark sql technologies.I had tried limit clause in spark sql. but it support only for particular limit starting from zero to that particular limit.But I want to retrieve rows from a specific start point to specific end point.Can you please anyone to suggest a method to achieve this.

```
Query1 :: SELECT * FROM `Emp` LIMIT 10;  - this query supports in both sql and spark sql
```

but

```
Query2 :: SELECT * FROM `Emp` LIMIT 10,20;  - to retrive rows from 10 to 20 supports in sql, but not in spark sql.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a modified LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM
(SELECT * FROM `Emp` LIMIT 20) a
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT * FROM `Emp` LIMIT 10) b
ON a.primary_key=b.primary_key
WHERE b.primary_key IS NULL
```

Comment: How can I execute this  query      SELECT * FROM `Emp` LIMIT 10,20;   in Spark sql to get rows between 10 and 20

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` in HQL

```
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER over (Order by id)  as rowid FROM `Emp`
where rowid > 10 and rowid <=20;
```

Comment: How can I execute this  query      SELECT * FROM `Emp` LIMIT 10,20;   in Spark sql to get rows between 10 and 20

Comment: the LIMIT 10,20 is meant for MySQL. I am not sure if the same syntax will work in Spark. You can try the above query for that.